# How can I make a substring from the word error to the first comma ','?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a substring of this type of messages that I send in PHP, I made a small code that works locally, but when I want that message to appear in my database I get a strange message.

This value wants to substring, this is the full text

```
Client error: `POST https://dev-platform.konfio.mx/core/transactions/424242/cancel` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
```

{"error": {"message": {"ticket": ["Missing data for required field."], "approvedBy": ["Missing data for required field." (truncated...)

I only want this substring:

```
{"error": {"message": {"ticket": ["Missing data for required field."]
```

This is the code that I made:

```
    $this->setTicketStatus('error');
    $message = $exception->getMessage();
    $pal = 'response:';
    $fin = ',';
    $pos_inicio = strripos($message, $pal) + 11;
    $pos_fin = stripos($message, $fin) - 1;
    $msg = array();
    $lon = strlen($message);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $lon; ++$i) {
        if ($i >= $pos_inicio and $i <= $pos_fin) {
            $msg[] = $i;
        }
    }
    $this->setMessageError(implode("|",$msg));
```

But I received this message, I don't why

```
Client error: `PUT https://dev-platform.konfio.mx/core/support/person/vasrvrvarvavrvrvw/birth` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"> <title>404 Not Found</title> <h1>Not Found</h1> <p>The requested (truncated...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the response appears to be a JSON string, you can parse the JSON and then get what you need:

```php
$data = json_decode(...);
$errorMessage = [];
$errorMessage['error']['message']['ticket'] = $data->error->message->ticket;
```

After the code runs, you can convert `$errorMessage` back into JSON if you'd like:

```php
echo json_encode($errorMessage);
```

Which would return:

```javascript
{"error": {"message": {"ticket": ["Missing data for required field."]}}}
```